# Authenticate with OAuth2 in Grails against GooglePlus

Tags: grails, plugins, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I want to integrate my Grails application with OAuth2 authentication against GooglePlus. In other words I want my users be able to login with their Google account on my site.

Which is the preferred way of doing this in grails? Which plugin is best suited?

I have been searching a lot. There is one specific plugin for facebook authentication but I haven't found one for google.

Thanks /Lasse

Comment: Oauth Plugin for Grails. http://grails.org/plugin/oauth

Comment: That's not Oauth2 I believe. I tried it. I believe it's based on Oauth. See, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455626/google-consent-screen-not-shown-as-expected.

Comment: I have updated the sample application https://github.com/manishkbharti/grailsOauthPluginDemo. Now it is using oauth2 for google authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google APIs for Java since Grails runs on the JVM, any Java library should work. That would be the preferred way for now as there is no grails-specific way of doing this.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

Google provides a sample application for google+ as a quickstart
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java