# OAuth 2.0 for Grails without Spring security

Tags: grails, oauth, spring-security, google-authentication, grails-2.3

I am currently implementing Shiro-Authentication along with OAuth for Google SignIn. It all works great and lets me authenticate a gmail account against a users email in my database. 
My build config looks as follows:

```
    //User roles and permissions
    compile (":shiro:1.2.0") {
        excludes "servlet-api"
        excludes "shiro-quartz"
    }

    //Google SignIn
    compile ":oauth:2.1.0"
```

The only issue I am having is that when google requests permission for my application, I get this: [image]

When I was expecting something more like this:[image]

It is clearly still using OAuth 1.0 and not 2.0.
I have read many questions on here and the closest I have found is this [Google consent screen not shown as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455626/google-consent-screen-not-shown-as-expected/20463966#comment35164192_20463966) .

The only issue with this implementation is that it uses Spring security and I am using Shiro. When I try use the spring plugin, I keep coming up against this issue when I try to compile it:

```
| Error The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1, org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.2.0.RC1: Could not find artifact org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.0.RC1 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.

IDEA hook: Grails not found!
| Error java.lang.NullPointerException
| Error     at org.jetbrains.groovy.grails.rt.Agent$2.run(Agent.java:135)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I am currently revisiting this issue. Anyone any ideas or links to similar questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create a [sample grails application](https://github.com/manishkbharti/grailsOauthPluginDemo) that uses `oauth plugin` for `google authentication` with `oauth2`.

Have a try.

I have created a new `java` file in `src/java` as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/yincrash/2465453), and using this in my google configurations in `Config.groovy`.

I have provided the full solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455626/google-consent-screen-not-shown-as-expected/23638872#23638872).